# How to add borderline between row items in prettytable?

Tags: prettytable

I'm using python [prettytable](https://github.com/jazzband/prettytable), and want to add borderlines between row items. Is there any idea? Or can I at least add padding between the rows?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution by setting

`from prettytable import PrettyTable, ALL
x = PrettyTable()
x.hrules=ALL`

it makes all dashed borderline between the rows.